# Upload large files using Ruby

Tags: ruby, webserver, sinatra, file-upload, large-files

I'm wondering what is the best pattern to allow large files to be uploaded to a server using Ruby.

I've found [Rails and Large, Large file Uploads: Looking at the alternative](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/04/10/rails-and-large-large-file-uploads-looking-at-the-alternatives/) but it doesn't give any concrete solutions.

I don't want to use Rails since I'm working on a simple upload server that'll run in standalone mode. I'm guessing that Sinatra could be the key but I don't know which web server I should use to run it without raising a Timeout.

I also need this web server to allow simultaneous upload.

**UPDATE:** By "large files" I mean between 200MB and 5GB.

**UPDATE2:** Since those files are videos (in my case), I can deal with a max size of 2GB like youtube.

Comment: Can you define 'large' files (general file size you are looking to upload)?

Comment: I would encourage you to think about leveraging S3 in this situation.  Housing large files like that can be expensive - S3 makes it fairly cheap.  If that is something you're interested in, take a look at using paperclip configured for s3.  That gem is generally used with Rails, but there's a solid chance you could get it to work with only Ruby.  -- I know this is pretty far from what you're asking for, hence the comment and not an answer.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

ok i am taking a bit of a strech here but:
if you would use a couchdb as a target for your uploads you would get rid of the timeout problem.
consider the couchdb as some "temp" memory in this example.
so if a downloads finishes you can take the file from the couchdb and do with it whatever you want.
i managed to upload files as big as 9gb over a dsl line into couchdb without any drama.
it may take a bit of reading but i think you could make it work.

couchdb has many rails gems so it plays nice with others ;)

let me know if you wanna go down that rabbit hole so i can give you some more pointers

Comment: I really like the idea. I'm giving it a try today :)

Comment: I think this is quite a stretch and seems quite odd that you need to implement a couchdb to your app just to support file uploading.  I like the idea and it might work for some.

Answer (score 0):

passenger recommends using a separate apache/nginx module to handle uploads.

Comment: Do you have a cue on how to implement this ? I can't find any doc about nginx+passenger handling large files.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like there's options for apache but not nginx? Maybe it's just a generic nginx directive as to where to allow uploads...

http://blog.schuerrer.org/post/571570048/file-upload-progress-done-right
might help